# WCF Multiple Interface

Tags: wcf, service, callback, duplex, endpoint

i am really wanting to get my head around this WCF technology and it seems the last months of information cramming has somewhat distorted my overall concept of how i should build my client/server application.

If someone out there could shed some light on the best practises when developing my app and implementing a Duplex WCF service with multiple interfaces.

General outline: I am wanting to develop an app where users connect to a server and lets say'.. add contacts to an sql database. I have discovered many ways of doing this but would ultimatly like to know im heading down the right path when it comes time to developing the app further.

Some models i have discovered are...

Client has its own LINQ to SQL classes and handles all data to and from data.... BAD. really slow. overheads with LINQ and SQL connections amongst poor implementation of Linq Select command.

Another model was the develop the service to implement the linq to sql commands which are used for CRUD operations however this still doesnt provide live data updates to other clients connected to the service.

So i made a basic app that when a client logs in the to the service there Callback Channel gets added to the Callback List. When a client feeds in a new contact to the service, it invokes a callback to all channel clients with the new contact and the client side function takes care of adding the contact to the right spot.

So now i want to implement a User object and perhaps 2 more other business objects say Project and Item and lets say Item... my idea is to create my service like this

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[ServiceBehavior(
   ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
   InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Project: IProject
       {
    [DataMember()]
    public int projectID;
          public int Insert(objSubItem _objSubItem)
    {
        // code here
               }
```

etc and

```
 [ServiceContract(
    Name = "Project",
    Namespace = "",
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract = typeof(IProjectCallback))]
public interface IProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inserting a Project record to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_project">Project from Client</param>
    /// <return>ProjectID back to the client if -1 then fail</return>
     [OperationContract()]
     int Insert(Project _project);
```

and

```
    public interface IProjectCallback
{
     /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the clients that a Project has been added
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_project">Inserted Project</param>
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NotifyProjectInserted(Project _project);
}
```

obviously i have other crud functions and functions to ensure that both client and server data records are read only when being editited.

now if i have multi objects what is it the best way to lay it out.

Im thinking to create a servce.cs and an Iservice.cs and an IserviceCallback to negotiate the client channel population.. sould i also use partial classes of the service to implement the Iproject and IUser to properly ivoke the service callbacks aswell as invoking the objects insert.

would i do it like this

```
 [ServiceContract(Name = "Service",
 Namespace = "", 
 SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, 
 CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallBack))]
 [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Project))]
 [ServiceKnownType(typeof(User))]
 public interface IService
 {

     // code here
 }
```

and also

```
    [ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, 
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public partial class Service :  IUser
    {

    public int Insert(User _User)
    {
       //       
    }
    }
    public partial class Service : IProject
    {

    public int Insert(Project _project)
    {
       // code here
    }
    }
    public partial class Service : IService
   {

    //   functions here 

    }
    }
```

if feels as though the approach feels right if it was for one interface but feel that i need some "Best Practice" assistance.

Many thanks in advance,,

Chris Leach

Hi Richard,
I appreciate your response. As you see this is my first post and third ever on any forum related to programming. I have lived my programming life very close to google as shown by my google autofill history but its time to start asking questions of my own so i thank-you for your assistance so far. I am really wanting to understand an overall approach to how best managing data consistency amongst a distributed client/service application. I am looking into Telerik ORM and also Entity Framework as a solution and exposing the entities through a WCF service but i lack the understanding to implement data consistency amongst the clients. i have managed to develop a netDualTcp chat application and have used a list of client callback context to send join/leave and chat functions. I lack the overall picture however it seems that if i have a in memory (static) version of all of the tables in my sql database and either have the clients bind directly to these lists if this is possible or it seems best for my custom user controls  to handle the connections so the server is aware of who has that particular user control open and can direct changes to those clients who are registered to the callback contract. that way the clients arent having to load the entire project every time they wish to open the application. I am thinking of a multi purpose application such as a contact/grant application program where users will be using different parts of the application and do not always need to access all of the information at one time. When the user first logs in i am hoping that the service will attach a callback contract for the client and several bits of information are loaded back to the client on authentaction such as a basic state i.e if they are an admin they get notifications etc. once they are logged in they are presented with a blank canvas but then begin to load custom user controls into a docking panel type interface. i guess this is where i become a little stuck about how to best manage concurrency and consistency whilst minimizing load/data transfer times to the client and freeing up cpu proccess time on both client. I know in programming there are multiple ways of doing this but i would like to know from the people on this forum what they feel the best approach to this type of soultion is. I understand its a deep topic but i feel i have come this far and a guiding hand would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Generally I find taking a non-abstract view of a service gets me to the right place. What is it that consumers of my service are going to need to do?

I obviously have internal domain objects that are used by my business layer to create and manipulate the data. However, the way the business layer does tings isn;t necessarily the best way to partition functionality for my service.

So for example, if any project should have at least one user in it then when you create the project you should send over at least one user at the same time. The service operations need to encapsulate all of the data required to carry out a self contained business transaction.

Similarly, the death knell of many distributed systems is latency - they require lots of round trips to complete something. So, for example, you want to be able to add a user to a project; in reality you probably want to add a number of users to as project. Therefore, you should model the operation to accept a list of users not a single one which must be invoked multiple times

So a project service should allow you to do all the things related to a project, or projects, through a service contract. If users can live independently of projects then also have a user service. If they cannot then don;t have a user service as everything needs to be project focussed.

Business transactions are often more than straight forward CRUD operations on domain entities and the service should model them rather than reflecting the data model

Comment: Thanks for your response Richard. I have left a note as an edit in my orignal post as i am new to stackoverflow and was limited to a few words as a reply topic. thank-you again for your response. chris